# Controlling PageBlockTable Table width

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, pageblocktable

I am having trouble setting the width of a table. I have tried using columnsWidth but it does not seem to respect it.

```
        <div class="column">
            <apex:pageBlock >
                  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.field1}" border="2" var="ac" style="-fs-table-paginate: paginate">
                      <apex:facet name="header">Test header</apex:facet>
                      <apex:column value="{!ac.field2}"> </apex:column>
                      <apex:column value="{!ac.field3}"> </apex:column>
                      <apex:column value="{!ac.field4}"> </apex:column>
                      <apex:column value="{!ac.field5}"> </apex:column>
                      <apex:column value="{!ac.field6}"> </apex:column>
                 </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock> 
        </div>  

        .column {
                 float: left;
                 overflow:auto;
                 width: 300px;
                 hight: 300px; 
                }
```

**Update: Changed code but the table still goes over to the right hand side of the PDF. However the text fields respect .column. Not sure why the table won't.**

Below is a picture of the above. On the left hand side you can see the table goes over to the next column. I want to control the width of this table to stay on the left hand side of the page. This is specified by .column css. The table should not go over to the right hand side and I am not sure how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the fix width of parent width to add scrollbar. So that it doesn't go to the next column.

```
<div class="column">
            <apex:pageBlock >

.column {
   overflow:auto;;
   width: 200px; //make sure you give height in px    
}
```

Comment: The tables are still not respecting this but the text fields are. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Mguy Are you getting any scrollbar? If no share your updated code.

Comment: Updated the code. Also this is a PDF as i'm using renderAs="pdf"

Comment: @Mguy if its a PDF I suggest you to try HTML table. As it will be much easy to handle and also give expected result.